# Sending email through Django, incorrect page rendered

Tags: django, django-views

Basically I am trying to send email to users when they click the activation link sent to their email when registered. The below code works fine and user does get the email however after email.sent() its goes to activation_invalid.html instead of activation_success.html

```
def account_activate(request, uidb64, token):
    try:
        uid = force_str(urlsafe_base64_decode(uidb64))
        user = UserBase.objects.get(pk=uid)
    except(TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, user.DoesNotExist):
        user = None
    if user is not None and account_activation_token.check_token(user, token):
        user.is_active = True
        user.save()
        login(request, user)
        current_site = get_current_site(request)
        subject = 'Activation Successful!'
        message = render_to_string('app/auth/email/account_activation_success_email.html', {
            'user': user,
            'domain': current_site.domain,
        })
        to_email = user.email
        email = EmailMessage(subject, message, to=[to_email])
        email.send()
        return render(request, 'app/auth/activation_success.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'app/auth/activation_invalid.html')
```

When I remove email.send(), activation_success.html is rendered like it should in the first place.